# Something very strange UITextView in iOS 7 ... not in iOS 6?

Tags: ios7, uitextview, memory-leaks, nsundomanager

I'm creating a UITextView:

```
greetingTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:greetingRect];
```

Using it fine, but when the ViewController it is attached to deallocs I'm getting memory leaks ONLY in iOS 7 ? I'm even Nulling the greetingTextView out of desperation but to no effect:

```
    [greetingTextView.undoManager removeAllActions];
    greetingTextView.delegate = Nil;
    [greetingTextView removeFromSuperview];
    greetingTextView = Nil;
```

The leaks are in this image:

[image]

So it appears something to do with the UITextView UndoManager ?  But why only in iOS 7 ?

Regards

Comment: did you find the answer? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Sorry no :( , maybe it;s a feature lol

Comment: I have the same problem, do you have any new information about this specific issue?

Comment: Experiencing the same stuff, no solution for now.

Comment: Nil is not the same as nil

Comment: technically Nil and nil are different, nil is the id of a null instance and Nil is the the id of a null class,  but in practice they are defined thus so it makes no difference in this case:                                                         #define nil __DARWIN_NULL
#define Nil __DARWIN_NULL

Comment: I'm getting the same leak. Maybe its a bug in iOS7? (I see its also there in iOS7.1)

Comment: And I've tried rewriting a totally new sample that just sets up an editable UITextView. As soon as you edit the text then exit the viewController it leaks the undoManager as shown above. 

I also tried  a few bits of sample code from elsewhere (e.g. Ray Wenderlich) and it has exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I face a similar situation, and after hunting around and some trail and error, i noticed that when ARC is disabled for that particular file, the strange behavior stopped and no memory leaks occurred. [check here for how to disable arc for a particular file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to empty out the undo manager if you want any object you add to it to be released.

Review the steps laid out in this document :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/CleaningUndoStack.html

Answer (score 0):

It did occurs to me once when I didn't specify the delegate of a UITextField. After the delegate was set everything went normal. Hope it helps. BTW, I'm using Storyboard.